# Decision trees sensitive to multiple copies in a training set

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

Are decision trees sensitive to adding multiple copies of the
same instance in the training set.

If yes, why ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation

For the creation of the tree you will split the remaining of your learning set with some criterion. The most commonly used is the augmentation of purity in the following leaves (purity can be viewed as having all the same classes in one leaf). If you define purity as a ratio between elements of class A and B per example the multiple copies will end up in the same leaf and skew the splits in their favor.

I know some implementation take that into account and use alternative criterions to overcome this problem.